# How can I take down SWAT Van Turrets?

Tags: payday-2

This has been a question that has been on my mind for quite a while. While I have played my share of heists, the one thing that always seems to stop me dead in my tracks, literally, seems to be those pesky Swat Van Turrets.

I have never been a fan of dodge builds, favoring the Good ol' Grinder. However, the lack of dodge leaves me in quite the predicament when I come face to face with those turrets.

My question is, **How can I take down those turrets? What is the recommended method? And will the vans "respawn" after a while?**

Comment: I'm honestly surprised this hadn't been asked yet on here, given how much of a "screw the players" move this was on Overkill's part. (If it was asked on here, I can't find it under the Payday-2 tag)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The swat turrets have a chance to appear on a few days:

- Harvest & Trustee (Bank Heist, all variants, as well as Firestarters Day 3)
- Hoxton Breakout Day 1
- Four Stores
- Meltdown (guaranteed spawn)
- GO Bank

There are probably others that I've missed.

All of the reliable methods to destroy the SWAT turrets that I am aware of unfortunately rely on paid DLC items, so if you only have the base game, you're kinda screwed. The most effective means to destroy a SWAT turret is a molotov (Butcher's BBQ Pack) to destroy the armor on it and then a DeathWish-Optimized weapon aimed at the lens of the turret itself (for critical damage). You either want the turret distracted or on cooldown (yellow laser) when you go in for the kill. Dodge also helps (although recent nerfs to a couple perk decks make dodge slightly less powerful). Once a turret is destroyed, it will remain destroyed, and a new turret will NOT take its place.

Outside of destroying turrets, there is a way to temporarily disable all turrets (or, more accurately, not have the turrets shoot at you). If you deploy an ECM, for the duration of the jamming effect, all turrets will be scrambled and will open fire on enemies. With four players fully maxed out for stealth, this comes to a 4-ish minute window maximum for getting past turrets.

Answer (score 2):

Turrets consist of "armor", and also the turret itself which has about 50000 HP. The armor blocks all damage until it is destroyed.

Fire will quickly burn the armor off, due to a small bug. Try throwing a molotov at it once it stops shooting (or your molotov will be shot out of the air). Once the armor is off, shoot right into the lens (where the laser comes out).

The armor has a damage clamp, which means that it will ignore damage above a certain point. Avoid using snipers and RPG's on the turret, until you get the protective shield off. Explosive damage is not clamped until a higher amount (55 instead of 11), so a shotgun with HE Shells is ideal. Since you're running Grinder, try a Judge.

The best weapons to use after the armor is off are sniper rifles, due to their high damage per shot. Assault Rifles and Akimbos with Low Blow work pretty well, too.

Vans will not respawn when destroyed.